# comparing date objects in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have two POJO's with fields of Date Type.
I am using Spring MVC and passing those two POJO's through `ModelAndView`.
I can compare those dates in controller using `compareTo()`.
I want to compare them in JSP page to hide or show some td's.

In controller this works:

```
for (AttendanceReport attendanceR2 : pastAttendance) {
    System.out.println("For date: "+ attendanceR2.getTrainingDate());

    for (Attendance attendance2 : absentCandidates) {
        if (attendance2.getDateOfAbsentee().compareTo(attendanceR2.getDateOfTraining())==0) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println(attendance2.getCandidate().getCandidateId() + "---- absent on--- "+ attendance2.getDateOfAbsentee());
        }
    }
}
```

I want this comparison in JSP also...**without any scriptlets**...!!
How can this be achieved...!!

I am setting the objects from controller as follows:

```
modelAndView.addObject("absentCandidates",absentCandidates);
modelAndView.addObject("pastAttendance",pastAttendance);
```

I tried this is my JSP Page...but it isnt working...

```
<c:forEach items="${pastAttendance}" var="pastAttendance">
<c:forEach items="${absentCandidates}" var="absentCandidates">
   <c:if test="${pastAttendance.getDateOfTraining==absentCandidates.getDateOfAbsentee}">
    <td>Some Check Box Unchecked</td>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

dateOfTraining and dateOfAbsentee, both are fields of Type Date...they just aren't getting compared in JSTL...

Comment: This is two years too late, but I seem to remember that in JSTL you remove the initial 'get' from get methods. So one reason is maybe because you should have written: **<c:if test="${pastAttendance.dateOfTraining eq absentCandidates.dateOfAbsentee}">**.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do your business logic in a servlet. In a servlet you prepare a data model which represents this table you want to conditionally build, and then in the JSP you simply loop over the generated datamodel using JSTL to generate the view you need.

Alternatively you might build the data model in a simple getter property of a POJO bean class so you don't need a servlet to do the preparation work.

Comment: Yes the table is getting generated just fine...just need to compare the date fields and accordingly place a checked or unchecked checkbox in the <td>...
see my edit...!!!